# How to access a doc's URL using REST API + JQuery in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: jquery, api, sharepoint

I am doing basic OData/REST calls to a SP2013 doc library. I am trying to get down to the item's URL and can't determine how to do this. I am very familiar with the server-side object model and understand that the file object is one level deeper than the item. Can someone point me in the right direction or share documentation on how to get down to the file level? I have scoured google. Here's my code that works for simply getting access to all the items in doc library and any metadata columns I wish to target:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>

<script>
    // workaround for access error
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    // create REST query
    var requestUri = "http://sp2013/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items"; 

    // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.d.results);
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
                if (item["Meta1"] == null) {
                    $("body").append("<h1>No Title</h1>");
                }
                else {
                    $("body").append("<h1>" + item["Meta1"] + "</h1>");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Of course I just figured it out by updating my URI with "/RootFolder/Files". My next question would be how I couple the URL of the doc with the metadata from the item...

Comment: Have you tried like this : _api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items(1)/File ?

Comment: Or /RootFolder/Files(1)/Item if you want to approach from file side.

Answer (score 16):

For the full url, try:

```
"http://sp2013/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl"
```

Comment: It's not a reference link.  If he were to use this string as his `requestUri` for the REST API call, it would return the absolute URLs of items in his documents list.

Answer (score 7):

Use the $select query option with `FileRef` parameter to return document Url:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileRef
```

### References

[Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) to do that -- but it's a third party library. In the [documentation](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.get) there is this example:

```
// if you want to list all the files and folders for a Document Library
$SP().list("My Shared Documents").get({
  fields:"BaseName,FileRef,FSObjType", // "BaseName" is the name of the file/folder; "FileRef" is the full path of the file/folder; "FSObjType" is 0 for a file and 1 for a folder (you need to apply $SP().cleanResult())
  folderOptions:{
    show:"FilesAndFolders_Recursive"
  }
});
```

At least that could give you some ideas.